# Laravel 5 csrf_token is mismatch with Session Id

Tags: php, laravel, csrf, laravel-5, csrf-protection

I'm fresh on laravel (5.2).

I try to check the csrf_token() and session::getId().

Both are not same.

What is wrong with that ?

My INPUT :

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
```

OUTPUT :

```
<input type="hidden" value="P7EO9KrUgv8JIgGS9WgtvhlBdttkQS7eLPsUTBy4" name="_token"></input>
```

csrf_token :

```
 P7EO9KrUgv8JIgGS9WgtvhlBdttkQS7eLPsUTBy4
```

Session ID :

```
 89a2f72ff042ab8c644fa651879d4057dafb0bb1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not related.

The CSRF token is stored inside the session, which is retrieved by the session ID.

Comment: is there any problem with that ?

Comment: What do you mean any problem?

Comment: Actually, i think this mismatch will rise "TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken " is it so ?

Comment: Nope, take a look at how the CSRF token is validate inside `\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken@tokensMatch`

Comment: It checks if inside the session there is a `_token` field and compare it to the input you provide